# JSON to Javascript hierarchy (array?)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dynamic-arrays

I would like to use the hierarchical structure of JSON, in a d3 tree layout such as in:

http://bl.ocks.org/1249394

In my work, I am using a variable in javascript:

```
var treeData = {
  "name" : "A1", "children" : [
    {"name" : "A3", "children": [
      {"name" : "A31", "children" :[
        {"name" : "A311" },
        {"name" : "A312" }
      ]}
    ]}
  ]};
```

How do I use this hierarchy as a *dynamic* javascript array, so that values can be pulled and new layers/branches in the hierarchy can be added or removed dynamically? Does this require a loop or empty arrays? I want to be able to create this hierarchy.
My main problem is that I don't know how to keep the hierarchical structure in the javascript array code.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: The code you've shown is a JS object with nested arrays of objects, it is _not_ JSON (which is a string representation, i.e., a serialisation of objects/arrays). If you're asking how to add and remove properties from objects you could probably get some tips from the MDN article [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: smh. I am sorry for that, yes it is a JS object. I made that mistake as I took the hierarchy out of a JSON file. Basically, I would like to create a nested set of arrays, to reflect this hierarchy structure as shown by the object above. But, I would like to do so dynamically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, after you assign value to treeData as you did above, it's already the hierachy you want. To manipulate them easier, you can do something like

```
tree.nodes(treeData);
```

to get an array of objects